# Date and time formatting in salesforce

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, datetime, date

Hi I need to convert the below date and time in the readable format is there any way because this value is coming from service and i am not understanding how to change this into readable format.

```
Value  :
dateOfExistence == 1998-10-13T12:00:15.278U

code 
 <div  title={dateOfExistence}>
                                    {dateOfExistence}
                                </div>
```

Comment: You need to replace the last U & it'll work. try new Date(dateOfExistence.replace('U',''));

Comment: Thankyou soo much @Sachin ..i got that working is there any way to change this if user hover over it ...will display the same value of lightning formatted text???

Comment: Yes, you can user onmouseover event. Simply add onmouseover attribute on the div & define a function for it.

Comment: ok...actully i was trying with the title property